# Calling a webservice using google closures jsonp and sending json as parameter

Tags: jsonp, google-closure

> I want to call a webservice using google closures, via jsonp since i am performing a cross domain webservice.
>
> And i am calling it in the following manner

```
var url = "http://myurl/";
var jsonp = new goog.net.Jsonp(url);
jsonp.send(
{"name":"jessi","action":"initaction","gameId":"123"},
callback, callbackfailed);
```

> But in this method the url is converted as a normal get method string as the follows

```
http://myurl/?name=jessi&action=initaction&gameId=123
```

> But i need to send this url as a json object in the following manner
> "name":"pari123","action":"initaction","gameId":"slotreel3"
>
> How can i do this, i searched google and i couldnt find proper documentation regarding ?this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function goog.net.Jsonp.addPayloadToUri_ that is used to encode the object says:

- @param {!Object} payload A map of value name pairs to be encoded.
- A value may be specified as an array, in which case a query parameter
- will be created for each value, e.g.:
- {"foo": [1,2]} will encode to "foo=1&foo=2".

This is exactly what is happening. So, why not initialize your url with the query? e.g.

```
var url = "http://myurl.php?" + goog.json.serialize({"name":"jessi","action":"initaction","gameId":"123"});
var jsonp = new goog.net.Jsonp(url);
jsonp.send()
```

Untested but maybe this works.

Regards,

Rene

Comment: What url (the query part) would you like to sent / is accepted by the webservice?